# MySQL query coming with white space at the end

Tags: php, mysql

While executing the following MySQL query to fetch the states of a country, I noticed that it is generating white space at the end when used in URLs.

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT bankName, state FROM table";
```

I checked with the csv file and found no white space at the end of any state in the state's column. Still I applied the `trim` function to the csv file but with no benefit.

How can I stop this white space?

Here is the code:-

```
<?php 
$remove[] = " ";
?>

<?php       
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','dbuser','password','dbname');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}           
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n";            
echo "<urlset xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'>\n";              
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT bankName, state FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);          
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                    
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                                              
echo "<url>\n";
echo "<loc>http://www.domainname.com/".str_replace($remove, "-", $row['bankName'])."/".str_replace($remove, "-", $row['state'])."/</loc>\n";                    
echo "<priority>0.8</priority>\n";
echo "</url>\n";
}
echo "</urlset>\n"; 
} else {
echo "<p>No result Found</p>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please post the sample code and expected answers.

Comment: What does a csv file have to do with MySQL in this problem? More details please...

Comment: <?php     
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT bankName, state FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);   
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {     
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {            
echo "<url>\n";
echo "<loc>http://domain.com/".str_replace($remove, "-", $row['bankName'])."/".str_replace($remove, "-", $row['state'])."/</loc>\n";     
echo "<priority>0.8</priority>\n";
echo "</url>\n";
}
echo "</urlset>\n"; 
} else {
echo "<p>No result Found</p>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: @VikasKukreja But give the output you are getting.

Comment: I used the above code for generating sitemap in xml way. Below are the result, please note the space before / at the end :

http://www.domain.com/Abhyudaya-Cooperative-Bank-Limited/Maharashtra / 0.8 http://www.domain.com/Abhyudaya-Cooperative-Bank-Limited/Gujarat / 0.8

Comment: @VikasKukreja Press the "edit" button just below your questions tags and paste the code into there, reading code in the comments is virtually impossible.

Comment: @foxbeefly I imported csv into mysql database and using mysql query to fetch results

Comment: How did you import the data from MySQL? How did you trim the values? Using PHP? Post your code.

Comment: @Epodax, I've added the code in my question

Comment: @foxbeefly I trimmed the column in excel then uploaded the csv file into mysql

Comment: My bad, I was checking as executable way, when I checked the source code of the live php file, I am getting the correct paths. Sorry everyone for the trouble :( and thanks for replies :)

Comment: Maybe a good idea to remove this question. It makes no sense and is not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having access to your csv data, or understanding how you got the csv into your database, the only solution I can offer is to attempt to remove "spaces" in your output code:

```
$stateName = trim($row['state']);
```

This should remove all whitespace - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php